# skip json array value in $.each loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

my json array `store` looks like this

```
[{
"role": "Executive Director",
"name": "David Z",
...},
{
"role": "Executive Director",
"name": "David Z",
...},
{
"role": "Non Executive Chairman",
"name": "Hersh M",
...},
{
"role": "Non Executive Director",
"name": "Alex C",
...},
{
"role": "Company Secretary",
"name": "Norman G",
...}]
```

from this array comes a few html tables.

I loop through `store` to a draw html table as part of an ajax success function, like this

```
var table = '';
table += '<tr><td......</td>';
$.each(store, function(i, data) {
   // draw row...
   // draw row etc...
});
table += '</tr></tbody>';
$("#table_d").append(table);
```

however for one of the tables I want to skip the 2nd occurrence of `David Z` (or whatever name that occurs more than once)

```
var table = '';
table += '<tr><td......</td>';
$.each(store, function(i, data) {
    if (i > 0, store[i].name != store[i-1].name) { 
       // draw row...
       // draw row etc...
    }
});
table += '</tr></tbody>';
$("#table_d").append(table);
```

the array will always be ordered so I can compare `store[i].name` against `store[i-1].name` for a duplicate `name`.

so how can I correctly express if `store[i].name != store[i-1].name` run loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you just need to do this

```
if(i > 0)
{
    if(store[i].name != store[i-1].name)
    {
        //run code here
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thanks. although that skips the first record. I am trying to include first record then each check each against previous?

Answer (score 1):

outside your each loop:

```
var names = new Array();
```

inside your each loop:

```
if(names.indexOf(store[i].name)==-1){
    names.push(store[i].name);
    //code here
}
```